# Is ArcFM or ArcMap leaking memory when switching between page templates?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, arcfm

Can anyone else reproduce the memory leak described below? Any insight into what may be causing the leak is appreciated.

I have custom code that swaps between landscape and portrait templates and exports a large number of maps to PDF. Unfortunately, there is a memory leak occurring when I swap from template to template that eventually causes the ArcMap to crash.

I can reproduce the memory leak using the Minerville data and workflow described below.

**Configuration:**

ArcFM Solution Desktop 10.1

ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop 10.1

Windows 7 64-bit or Windows XP 32-bit or Windows 2008 64-bit

**Workflow:**

1) Open Minerville database in ArcMap

2) Open “Stored Items” dropdown

3) Select “Page Templates” tab

4) Double-click the “Adjacent Grids” template to load it

5) Repeat steps 2-3 and double-click “Designer Detail Map Sheet”

6) Repeat steps 2 – 5 and watch memory usage climb in task manager

Using UMDH, the largest ArcFM-related offenders seem to be these:

Stack #1:

```
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+00000274
KERNELBASE!LocalAlloc+0000005F
GDI32!pmfAllocMF+0000018C
GDI32!SetEnhMetaFileBits+00000033
OLEAUT32!_PictLoadUnknownMetaFile+00000088
OLEAUT32!_PictLoadNewImage+000001A0
OLEAUT32!_PictLoadPicture+00000025
OLEAUT32!CPicture::Load+00000027
SystemCore!ObjectStream::LoadObject+000003E9
AfCore!LoadObject+0000005E
RasterGraphicElements!BasePictureElement::Load+000000ED
SystemCore!ObjectStream::LoadObject+000003E9
AfCore!LoadObject+0000005E
AfCore!ExtraSafeReadObject+00000072
PageLayout!PageLayout::Load+00000174
SystemCore!ObjectStream::LoadObject+000003E9
MMStoredStuff!DllGetClassesForCategoryReg+00011B32
MMStoredStuff!???+00000000 : 2DB04186
MMStoredStuff!DllGetClassesForCategoryReg+0000D9E5
MMStoredStuff!DllGetClassesForCategoryReg+0000C297
mmPageTemplatesUI!DllCanUnloadNow+00020402
mmPageTemplatesUI!DllCanUnloadNow+00038EAF
mmFrameworkListObjects!DllGetClassesAndCategories+000C38DC
mscorwks!CLRToCOMWorker+0000019A
```

Stack #2:

```
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+00000274
MSVCR90!malloc+00000079
MSVCR90!operator new+0000001F
DisplayCore!ClassFactory<CartographicLineSymbol>::CreateInstance+000000D8
AfCore!FactoryCache::CreateInstance+00000095
AfCore!FactoryCacheDispatcher::CreateInstance+00000050
AfCore!AfCreateInstance+00000040
SystemCore!ObjectStream::LoadObject+00000297
AfCore!LoadObject+0000005E
DisplayCore!MultiLayerLineSymbol::Load+000000F8
SystemCore!ObjectStream::LoadObject+000003E9
AfCore!LoadObject+0000005E
GraphicElements!LineElement::Load+00000076
SystemCore!ObjectStream::LoadObject+000003E9
AfCore!LoadObject+0000005E
GraphicElements!GroupElement::Load+00000082
SystemCore!ObjectStream::LoadObject+000003E9
AfCore!LoadObject+0000005E
AfCore!ExtraSafeReadObject+00000072
PageLayout!PageLayout::Load+00000174
SystemCore!ObjectStream::LoadObject+000003E9
MMStoredStuff!DllGetClassesForCategoryReg+00011B32
MMStoredStuff!???+00000000 : 2DB04186
MMStoredStuff!DllGetClassesForCategoryReg+0000D9E5
MMStoredStuff!DllGetClassesForCategoryReg+0000C297
mmPageTemplatesUI!DllCanUnloadNow+00020402
mmPageTemplatesUI!DllCanUnloadNow+00038EAF
mmFrameworkListObjects!DllGetClassesAndCategories+000C38DC
mscorwks!CLRToCOMWorker+0000019A
```

UPDATE #1:

Schneider Electric's support was able to reproduce the problem and has created a bug. I was told that if a fix was made at all, it would not be available until the 10.2 release.

I'll post more as I get more information.

Comment: +1 for showing usefulness of [UMDH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I hate to be snarky, but why not both?

Answer (score 2):

I also face similar situation when i was updating entire feature class and i notice that  arcFM autoupdators causing the memory leak.

```
while ((fcDeviceGroup = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
                        {
                            long mem1 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
                            _log.Debug("Memory Before " + mem1);
                            Debug.Print("Memory Before {0}", mem1);                          
                            processed++;
                            Console.WriteLine("Processing " + processed + " in total features: " + count);
                            if (!indexStrc)
                            {
                                structureGuid = fcDeviceGroup.Fields.FindField("globalid");
                            }
                            STRUCTUREGUID = Convert.ToString(fcDeviceGroup.get_Value(structureGuid));
                            GetOpenPointDictionary(STRUCTUREGUID, openPoint, checkStatus, busBar, ref indexSet, ref indexOpVolt);
                            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(fcDeviceGroup);
                            long mem2 = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
                            Debug.Print("Memory After {0}", mem2);
                            Debug.Print("Difference {0}", mem1 - mem2);
                            _log.Debug("Memory After " + mem2);
                            _log.Debug("Difference " + Convert.ToString(mem1 - mem2));
                        }
                        if (featureCursor != null)
                        {
                            while (Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(featureCursor) > 0) { }
                        }

This is code i was using to check for memory leak. When autoupdors was enable then every iteration memory sampling was.
2014-09-19 10:28:02,764 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 863664
2014-09-19 10:28:02,764 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:02,777 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 863804
2014-09-19 10:28:03,532 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864196
2014-09-19 10:28:03,936 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory Update Operation****************** 864508
2014-09-19 10:28:03,938 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - ****************Difference 312
2014-09-19 10:28:03,946 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 863940
2014-09-19 10:28:03,946 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference -136
2014-09-19 10:28:03,962 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 863920
2014-09-19 10:28:04,180 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 863960
2014-09-19 10:28:04,199 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 863876
2014-09-19 10:28:04,200 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 44
2014-09-19 10:28:04,212 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864016
2014-09-19 10:28:04,702 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864348
2014-09-19 10:28:05,052 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory Update Operation****************** 864656
2014-09-19 10:28:05,055 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - ****************Difference 308
2014-09-19 10:28:05,063 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864156
2014-09-19 10:28:05,063 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference -140
2014-09-19 10:28:05,070 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864136
2014-09-19 10:28:05,957 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864624
2014-09-19 10:28:06,287 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory Update Operation****************** 864936
2014-09-19 10:28:06,288 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - ****************Difference 312
2014-09-19 10:28:06,291 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864376
2014-09-19 10:28:06,291 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference -240
2014-09-19 10:28:06,300 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864356
2014-09-19 10:28:07,129 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864960
2014-09-19 10:28:07,585 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory Update Operation****************** 865272
2014-09-19 10:28:07,588 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - ****************Difference 312
2014-09-19 10:28:07,594 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864588
2014-09-19 10:28:07,595 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference -232
2014-09-19 10:28:07,613 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864568
2014-09-19 10:28:07,843 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:07,865 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:07,866 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 44
2014-09-19 10:28:07,878 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
2014-09-19 10:28:07,968 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:07,990 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:07,991 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:08,003 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
2014-09-19 10:28:08,101 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:08,114 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:08,115 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:08,127 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
2014-09-19 10:28:08,232 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:08,255 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:08,256 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:08,268 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
2014-09-19 10:28:08,361 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:08,380 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:08,380 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:08,393 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
2014-09-19 10:28:08,495 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:08,520 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:08,521 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:08,533 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
2014-09-19 10:28:08,638 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:08,661 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:08,661 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:08,673 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
2014-09-19 10:28:08,764 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:08,786 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:08,787 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:08,798 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
2014-09-19 10:28:08,892 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - *****************Memory After adding every thing in dictionary****************** 864608
2014-09-19 10:28:08,909 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory After 864524
2014-09-19 10:28:08,910 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Difference 140
2014-09-19 10:28:08,923 [17856] DEBUG OperatingVoltComparison.Program [(null)] <(null)> - Memory Before 864664
```

After disabling AU's memory consumption almost stable. For disabling AU's, I used following code.

```
 private static mmAutoUpdaterMode EnableAutoupdaters()
        {
            object objAutoUpdater = null;
            //Create an MMAutoupdater 
            objAutoUpdater = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("mmGeodatabase.MMAutoUpdater"));
            autoupdater = objAutoUpdater as IMMAutoUpdater;
            //Save the existing mode
            mmAutoUpdaterMode oldMode = autoupdater.AutoUpdaterMode;//autoupdater.AutoUpdaterMode
            //Turn off autoupdater events
            autoupdater.AutoUpdaterMode = mmAutoUpdaterMode.mmAUMNoEvents;//mmAutoUpdaterMode.mmAUMStandAlone

            return oldMode;
        }
```

You can call this method before doing any DML operation. I hope this will help to find the problem.